# How to call my method in the main method c#?

Tags: c#

I am currently learning C#. I want to try the following function, but I don't know what I need to put in the main method in order for it to run successfully:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    public class Program
    {
        public int[] SwitchLights(int[] a)
        {
            var count = a.Count(t => t == 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                var current = count;
                if (a[i] == 1) count--;
                if (current % 2 == 1) a[i] = a[i] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
            }
            return a;
        }
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: SwitchLights needs to be static.

Comment: You need to go through the documentation and proper tutorial set about OOP concepts...and data structures don't be lazy ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have to **either**

1, make the method **static**

```
    public static int[] SwitchLights(int[] a)
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         SwitchLights(new [] { 1 });
    }
```

Or 2, create an instance of Program class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var program = new Program();
         program.SwitchLights(new [] { 1 });
    }
```